# Can you assign a default enum value for failed casts in c++?

Tags: c++, enums

I'm wondering if it's possible to assign a default value to an enum in C++? That is to say, if we try to convert a value to this specific enum, and the value does not exist, have it return a default enum value...

```
enum ExampleEnum : int
{
    DefaultValue = 0,
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2;
};

// I want this to return 0 (DefaultValue) as the value (3) is not defined in ExampleEnum.
const ExampleEnum invalid_enum = static_cast<ExampleEnum>(3);
```

Comment: You'll need a validating conversion function.  A cast won't do it.

Comment: No, the enum values don't exist at runtime they're compile time only

Comment: *"and the value does not exist"* -- better would be to call this "the value does not have a name". In your example, you have specified `int` as the underlying type, and `3` certainly does exist as an `int` value.

Comment: *"if we try to convert a value to this specific enum"* -- is this supposed to be *"if we try to convert a value to this specific enum **with `static_cast`**"*? Because if you open up the conversion to a function you write, the answer becomes rather trivially "yes, a computer is capable of the task".

Comment: 3 is a valid value for `ExampleEnum`, even though it doesn't have a name. If you want to manage conversions yourself, write your own function to convert integer values to your type, and do whatever is appropriate.

Comment: with magic_enum it's trivial - https://godbolt.org/z/oqvnfYh34

Comment: Any value that fits in a `enum`s underlying type is valid, regardless of it having a name or not.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no such built-in feature and you can't affect what the `static_cast<ExampleEnum>` will do. Of course you can just write yourself a function that will perform the cast with a prior check of the value and use that instead of `static_cast`.

But also note that the cast `static_cast<ExampleEnum>(3)` is valid and that `3` is an allowed value of your enumeration type. An enumeration with a fixed underlying type (e.g. the one which has a type explicitly specified as you did) has all the values of its underlying type as valid values.

The named enumerators in the enumeration definition are just aliases for a subset of the values. They don't affect the range of possible values in this case.

(Beware though that this is different for enumerations without fixed underlying type.)