# Can I cast a number into an enum, safely, with a fallback value?

Tags: c++, reflection, enums, casting, static-reflection

I would like to write something like:

```
template <typename E, E fallback>
E safe_cast_to_enum(std::underlying_type_t<E> e);
```

which, for an enum class (or just an enum?) E, casts `e` to a corresponding value of `E`, if such a value exists, and to value `fallback` otherwise.

Can I do this generically?

Notes:

- I suspect the answer is negative until at least C++20, but regardless - please (also) answer using the earliest C++ version with which this is possible.
- If you like, you may assume `fallback` is a 'valid' value of the enum, i.e. it has an associated named identifier.
- If you can offer a solution based on somewhat stronger assumptions (underlying type size, nature of the set of values covered by the enum identifiers, known last value etc.), but which is still a general template rather than a different per-enum implementation - that is a useful, albeit imperfect, answer.

See also:

- [Can you assign a default enum value for failed casts in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74593508/1593077)
- [How to cast int to enum in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11452920/1593077)
- [What happens if you static_cast invalid value to enum class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18195312/1593077)

Comment: I think that without additional constraints on the enum actual values, there is no solution. The comments in the first linked post are pointing to magic_enum but this lib only works with some restriction on the actual values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you assign a default enum value for failed casts in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74593508/can-you-assign-a-default-enum-value-for-failed-casts-in-c)

Comment: @Oersted: No, because that question regards having the compiler recognize a default value, and apply it when using a cast operator. Here, I'm not requiring that.

Comment: Without reflection, it isn't possible in the general case. A partial solution with an upper bound at the scale of  4K can be crafted without code generators; this covers a lot of cases, but is not a full-range solution. If the underlying type is an octet, the solution is full-range.

Comment: @Red.Wave : 1. Why would an "upper bound of 4k" be meaningful/useful? 2. Suppose I let you assume the underlying bound is an octet; do you  have a solution then? That would definitely be an answer.

Comment: The limit depends on platform and comes from the maximum value fir which `std::make_index_sequence` doesn't ICE. On MSVC, default implementation with compiler intrinsics ICEs at 8k; My own implementation ICEd at 4k. So going far beyond 1k is not portable.

Answer (score 1):

As of C++23, no standard mechanism for obtaining a list of valid values for an enum exists.

However, it is possible to use some incredibly janky compiler-specific code to extract this information.

The [magic_enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum) library implements this code for the mainstream compilers.

Comment: Nitpick: One may not need to a list of values, but rather just have "oracle access" to checking whether a value corresponds to any named identifier; and those two are not exactly the same. Also, I don't suppose you can provide an example of janky compiler-specific facilities for this?

Comment: @einpoklum You can read the implementation of magic_enum if you want. The core idea is to have a `template <typename E, E value> void fn();` and inside this function read the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro. The compiler maps the numeric value to a constant name if possible to create the pretty function name's template arguments. You can then look at specific hardcoded offsets to see if there's a number there or a name.

Comment: However, since the value must be supplied at compile time, you can't use this as an easy oracle for "does value exist". Instead, magic_enum simply tries every value within some bounds (-128 to 128 by default) and sees what values come up.

Comment: see https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum/blob/master/doc/limitations.md. Noticeably, no aliased values.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a function that finds enum names:

```
template<auto value>
requires std::is_enum_v<std::decay_t<decltype(value)>>
consteval std::string_view enum_name() {
    constexpr static auto location=std::source_location::current();
    constexpr static std::string_view full_name= location.function_name();
    constexpr static auto closeb = full_name.rfind('>');
    constexpr static auto openb = full_name.find("<", 0, closeb);
    return full_name.substr(openb, closeb - openb);
};
```

Next we must make sure the result of above function is not a conversion expression. This part is greatly platform dependent:

```
constexpr bool is_enum_name(std::string_view name){
    if (auto brace = name.find_last_of("})"); brace==name.npos)
        return true;
    else
        return name.find(':',brace)!=name.npos;
};
```

Conversion expression is impossible without braces. If after the last closing brace, there's a scope operator(`::`), then it must be part of the `enum class` name qualifier; otherwise a conversion has happened.
Next we need to put the names and validators in a constexpr array. We can do different things now; I choose to store the raw values:

```
template<auto value>
requires std::is_enum_v<std::decay_t<decltype(value)>>
using enum_limits =
      std::numeric_limits<
      std::underlying_type_t<
      std::decay_t< decltype(value)
>>>;
template<typename enm>
requires std::is_enum_v<enm>
constexpr auto enum_strings = []<std::size_t ...i>{
    return std::array{
           enum_name< enm{ static_cast<
           std::underlying_type_t<enm>>(i)
}>()...};
}( std::make_index_sequence
 < std::min(1<<14
 , std::size_t
 { std::enum_limits<enm{}>::max()
 - std::enum_limits<enm{}>::min()
})>);
```

Now you can use the above LUT to your liking. It is possible to create a validator array of `bool` as well, but I leave that one for now. It is also possible to use `std::optional` or store empty `string_view` for invalid values.

```
template<auto value>
requires std::is_enum_v<std::decay_t<decltype(value)>>
constexpr decltype(value) 
to_enum( std::underlying_type_t
       < std::decay_t
       < decltype(value)>> num){
   if (std::bit_cast<std::size_t>(num)
   auto idx = static_cast<std::size_t>(num) 
            - enum_limits<value>::min();
   return is_enum_name
        ( enum_string
        < std::decay_t
        < decltype(value)
        >>[idx] )
        ? decltype(value){num}
        : value;
};
```

I have not run a test on this code; so there are probably lots of bugs and errors. But that happens when a header only library is composed as an answer. But it can give ideas on how some basic metadata about enums can be reflected. This is also pretty ugly and needs a lot of refactoring for readability.

Comment: You're missing an `auto` for closeb. And even if you fix that - [this doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/z/M8v8MqGPW).

Comment: There's a lot to fix. It's a jeader-only library and needs more polishing. Did you get the main Idea?

Comment: `consteval` is a function specific specifier. Your snippet applied it to object. Replace it with `constexpr` or totally remove it.